# How to let the user be able to change his answer to one of the questions in the quiz?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The web application that I am developing right now has something called quiz engine which provides users with short quizzes which consist of one question or more. Now, I have a problem with taking/ answering the quiz:
When the user finishes the quiz and he goes to the Result Page and he goes back to the Quiz page and answers the same question, he will get two results and I don't know why !!!

In brief, answering same question multiple times should not create multiple entries.

For creating the Quiz engine, I used  the Toturial for the Quiz Engine in the ASP.NET website for creating what I have.

My Code-Behind:

This is the code that is responsible for saving the answers:

```
protected void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save off previous answers
        System.Data.DataRowView dr = (System.Data.DataRowView)questionDetails.DataItem;

        // Create Answer object to save values
        Answer a = new Answer();
        a.QuestionID = dr["QuestionOrder"].ToString();
        a.CorrectAnswer = dr["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
        a.UserAnswer = answerDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();

        ArrayList al = (ArrayList)Session["AnswerList"];
        al.Add(a);

        Session.Add("AnswerList", al);

        if (questionDetails.PageIndex == questionDetails.PageCount - 1)
        {
            // Go to evaluate answers
            Response.Redirect("Results.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            questionDetails.PageIndex++;
        }

        if (questionDetails.PageIndex == questionDetails.PageCount - 1)
        {
            nextButton.Text = "Finished";
        }

    }
```

**So now how I can let the user be able to change his answer (or goes back to one of the answered questions) and this new answer will replace the previous one (not to be considered that the user answered the same question twice). How to do that?**

**EDIT:**

The following code is responsible for saving the result:

```
resultGrid.DataSource = al;
        resultGrid.DataBind();

        // Save the results into the database.
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // Calculate score
            double questions = al.Count;
            double correct = 0.0;


            for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
            {
                Answer a = (Answer)al[i];
                if (a.Result == Answer.ResultValue.Correct)
                    correct++;
            }

            double score = (correct / questions) * 100;
            string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString().Replace("ARAMCO\\", "");
            SqlDataSource userQuizDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
            userQuizDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ToString();
            userQuizDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [UserQuiz] ([QuizID], [DateTimeComplete], [Score], [Username]) VALUES (@QuizID, @DateTimeComplete, @Score, @Username)";

            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("QuizID", Session["QuizID"].ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateTimeComplete", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("Score", score.ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("Username", username);

            int rowsAffected = userQuizDataSource.Insert();
            if (rowsAffected == 0)
            {
                // Let's just notify that the insertion didn't
                // work, but let' s continue on ...
                errorLabel.Text = "There was a problem saving your quiz results into our database.  Therefore, the results from this quiz will not be displayed on the list on the main menu.";


            }

        }
```

Comment: How are you saving the answered list of the user ?

Comment: I edited my question with the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what can you try

Before you add answer to AnswerList, check if that question already exists in the list, if yes replace that with the current. **This you will have to do when you are saving the answer to DB.** The code below will update the object in Session only.

```
 // Create Answer object to save values
 Answer a = new Answer();
 a.QuestionID = dr["QuestionOrder"].ToString();
 a.CorrectAnswer = dr["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
 a.UserAnswer = answerDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();

 ArrayList al = (ArrayList)Session["AnswerList"];
 var oldAnswer = al.ToArray().Where(ans => (ans as Answer).QuestionID == a.QuestionID);
 if (oldAnswer.Count() != 0)
 {
      a = oldAnswer.FirstOrDefault() as Answer;
      a.CorrectAnswer = dr["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
      a.UserAnswer = answerDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();
 }
 else
 {
      al.Add(a);
 }

 //Rest of your code
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But by the way, I copied your code to mine and I got many errors during debugging it and I don't know why. I got the following error: Error 27 'object[]' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'object[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: "Where" is an extension method, defined in "System.Linq". It is available in .net 3.5 onwards. Using "Where" query, I'm just checking if that object already exists in the Session or not, you can do that in loop also. Also make sure you do it for the DB also, check if the question is answered by the same user earlier or not.

Comment: Looking at your code for saving answer in DB, you will have to use UpdateCommand if the same question is answered by the same user earlier. I hope your database table has some UniqueId/RowId for each record, you can use the same for updating the record.

Comment: But I am trying to modify something which is now assume we have a quiz of three questions; if the user answers the first question with B and the second question with C and when he goes to the third question, he decides to go back to the first question, so he will click back button two times when he changes his answer for the first question to A then he goes to the second question, he will also see the answer for the second question as A. I don't know why. The answer will be shown in the dropdownlist itself. I think I have a problem with the DropDownList but I don't know how to fix it. Any Idea

Comment: Sorry my friend, but I didn't get what r u trying to say. Try to debug the application, it must be some minor glitch in binding the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think When your logic is good.And also i apply same logic for this one.But when user click previous that time you have to clear that particular session and add new one. And also add finish button for exit.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I added the FINISHED button but I need now to modify this thing and I don't know how.